# Adding logging info to every request in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

As part of a security review, a customer is asking us to add logging info to each request to our website.  For example, in a Python/Flask app, I could do this:

```
@app.before_request
def log_stuff():
    logging.info('something really important')
```

This may be a dumb question, but would doing this significantly increase GAE operating costs.  I suspect not, but wanted to make sure I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You might need some more space, depending how extensive your log messages are, how many logs you want to store and how high your traffic is. But since 1 GB is far less than 1$ per month, you should not see a significant increase in your GAE costs.

You could just write an example logging message and calculate, how much space you will need for an expected number of requests and for how long this shall be stored.
But this should not have any big impact. This is no complex operation, the only thing you should consider is the diskspace you might need in addition.

Answer (score 1):

creolo's answer is correct, but I'll add some...

You might want to put some logic to only log outside requests, or special logging for internals.  Something like:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    # if you want to stop checking when in dev:
    if app.config["DEBUG"]:
        return None
        
    if request.headers.get('User-Agent', 'na').startswith('AppEngine-Google'):
        ...
    if request.path.startswith('/admin/'):
        ...
    if current_user.is_active:
        ...
    if current_user.is_superuser:
        ...

    return None
```

Also, if space becomes an issue, you can save a very small amount of disk space by customizing your logging config to shorten it, or just use a `print()` statement:

```
import logging

LOGGING_FORMAT      = '%(levelname).1s %(message).25s'
LOGGING_DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'    #,%(msecs)d
LOGGING_LEVEL       = logging.DEBUG

logging.basicConfig(format=LOGGING_FORMAT, datefmt=LOGGING_DATE_FORMAT, level=LOGGING_LEVEL)
```

More at: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#changing-the-format-of-displayed-messages

Comment: To avoid space issues, you can also think about compressing your log files. This can safe you up to 90% of the space. Because we were not satisfied with the python build in login handler we wrote our own handler that compresses the logs directly,  which can safe you a lot of space. We just uploaded it to pypi today, it is called [compressedlogger](https://pypi.org/project/compressedlogger/).

Sorry for this advertisement', maybe this is  useful